# still can access the proguard apk?

Tags: java, android, proguard

i'm trying to secure my code this time as i've got some of my apps out there copied ! but i dont seem to know the right way to do a proguard, iv even tried an online website to encrypt it but it does not seem to work, after i add this to the project.properties

> To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this
>   (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
>   proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

i still can access my java files using dex2jar ! anyone knows a way to secure java android code ?

Comment: Yes you can access the java file after proguard but it's so complex and easy to understand the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will be obfuscated when you'll do the release build (Export option in Eclipse).

You can also keep proguard configuration in proguard.cfg in the same directory as project.properties. This way you could modify file with some project-specific settings.

- project.properties

> ```
> # Project target.
> target=android-15
>
> #Proguard config
> proguard.config=proguard.cfg
> ```

- proguard.cfg (in the same directory as project.properties)

> ```
> -optimizationpasses 5
> -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
> -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
> -dontpreverify
> -verbose
> -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
> -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
> -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
> -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
> -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
> -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     native <methods>;
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
> }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
>    public void *(android.view.View);
> }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>     public static **[] values();
>     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
> }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
> }
>
> -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
>     public static *** d(...);
>     public static *** v(...);
> }
> ```

Comment: i did this, still nothing, i can still access it all with dex2jar, any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have following line in project properties?

#Proguard config
proguard.config=proguard.cfg

Comment: nop, but i do have this       # To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Comment: Ok, so go ahead and uncomment it. Hash sign (#) before proguard.config means this variable is still commented.

Comment: yes i did that, and unfortunately it did no good i still can accesee the java code with dex2jar, i'm not sure why ?

Comment: I've edited my post. Please configure your project in the exact same way.